# Get streamed file size from grpc server interceptor

Tags: go, grpc, middleware, interceptor, go-grpc-middleware

I have a Go server bidirectional stream method defined like this in proto-file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option go_package="pdfcompose/;pdfcompose";
package pdfcompose;

service PdfCompose {
  rpc Send (stream FileForm) returns (stream PdfFile) {}
}

message FileForm {
  bytes Upfile1 = 1;
  bytes Upfile2 = 2;
  bytes Upfile3 = 3;
}

message PdfFile {
  bytes File = 1;
}
```

And my log interceptor has the following interface:

```
func logInterceptor(srv interface{}, ss grpc.ServerStream, info *grpc.StreamServerInfo, handler grpc.StreamHandler)  error {
    fmt.Println("Log Interceptor")
    err := handler(srv, ss)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

And I'm using https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware as an interceptor engine.
I need to implement logging of the streaming file size (for educational purposes) and trying to find out where I can get any data about FileForm and it contents.

My first guess was to look into grpc.ServerStream argument (ss) to find something about it and it looks like it contains a lot of data like max and min MessageSize, but noting about actual content length.

How I can get size of incoming file with this kind of interceptors?

Comment: As the content is being streamed it will arrive over time (so the info is not available at the time the interceptor is called; you need to wait on `handler`). Are you looking to raise a log entry as each `PdfFile` is received (easier to do this in the handler rather than an interceptor) or just the total bytes processed (only known when the stream is closed; think this would require a [wrappedStream](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/blob/master/tags/interceptors.go#L28)).

Comment: Yes, you're right, this is actually how aI succeed to implement this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as @Brits has mentioned above, the working way to implement what I wanted is to write wrapper for stream.

Here is an example: https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/blob/master/validator/validator.go I took the following code from this repo and I hope I understand apache2 license correct and there is no issues with copying a part of this code:

```
// StreamServerInterceptor returns a new streaming server interceptor that validates incoming messages.
//
// The stage at which invalid messages will be rejected with `InvalidArgument` varies based on the
// type of the RPC. For `ServerStream` (1:m) requests, it will happen before reaching any userspace
// handlers. For `ClientStream` (n:1) or `BidiStream` (n:m) RPCs, the messages will be rejected on
// calls to `stream.Recv()`.
func StreamServerInterceptor() grpc.StreamServerInterceptor {
    return func(srv interface{}, stream grpc.ServerStream, info *grpc.StreamServerInfo, handler grpc.StreamHandler) error {
        wrapper := &recvWrapper{stream}
        return handler(srv, wrapper)
    }
}

type recvWrapper struct {
    grpc.ServerStream
}

func (s *recvWrapper) RecvMsg(m interface{}) error {
    if err := s.ServerStream.RecvMsg(m); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := validate(m); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

`validate()` function actually gets request as `interface{}` and you need to use type assertion to cast this request to type you needed as `v := req.(type)`.

For example, I typed request to `FileForm` and was able to check it's content:

```
func logFileSize(req interface{}) error {
    m := req.(*pdfcompose.FileForm)
    println("SizeOfUpfile1: " + strconv.Itoa(int(binary.Size(m.Upfile1))))

    if m.Upfile2 != nil {
        println("SizeOfUpfile2: " + strconv.Itoa(int(binary.Size(m.Upfile3))))
    }
    if m.Upfile3 != nil {
        println("SizeOfUpfile2: " + strconv.Itoa(int(binary.Size(m.Upfile3))))
    }
    return nil
}

func (s *recvWrapper) RecvMsg(m interface{}) error {
    if err := s.ServerStream.RecvMsg(m); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    //z := m.(pdfcompose.FileForm)
    if err := logFileSize(m); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func StreamServerInterceptor() grpc.StreamServerInterceptor {
    return func(srv interface{}, stream grpc.ServerStream, info *grpc.StreamServerInfo, handler grpc.StreamHandler) error {
        wrapper := &recvWrapper{stream}
        return handler(srv, wrapper)
    }
}
```